# How to calculate/profile percentage of parallelized C# Code

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Greeting,

I'm working on performance improvement for my application by enabling the multi-thread. I learned from the "[Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)", it requires >50% of parallelized code to achieve 2x speedup in 8 cores processor. Hence I just wondering is there any tool in the market provides parallelized code coverage or profiling that can help me to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you're using vs 2010, you can use the concurrency visualizer for profiling multi-threaded apps.](http://services.social.microsoft.com/feeds/FeedItem?feedId=d412920e-1bff-4116-ad5d-db80a410b5e3&itemId=f2e01832-1f0e-4032-85e1-901027b48850&title=Optimizing+Parallel+Applications+Using+Concurrency+Visualizer%3a+A+Case+Study&uri=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2fB%2fC%2fF%2fBCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D%2fOptimizingUsingConcurrencyVisualizer.pdf&k=r%2f0WAdguOQ8vlQhWwwKLR3f9tf4OZL1rj7Rp33Rpnp8%3d)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4.0 then

Use Task Parallel Library , Parallel Loops

i have herad of [Jinx](http://www.corensic.com/) but this is for code analyzing / debugging may be of any help